# Grouping your CSS classes to streamline your stylesheet

Tags: css

Here is my Problem I am making a nav bar with drop downs. I already have a class for all li in a list. Here is the CSS for that.

```
#menu li:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777777;
    padding: 4px 5px 4px 5px;
}

#menu li a {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px; 
    color: #EEEEEE;
}

#menu li:hover a {
    color:#161616;
}
```

Here is how this implemented.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Button 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Button 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Button 2</a></li>
```

I want to create a Class called nodropdown using the css above. This is how I formated it but I don't think I did it correctly.

```
#menu li.nodropdown :hover {
    border: 1px solid #777777;
    padding: 4px 5px 4px 5px;
}

#menu li.nodropdown a {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px; 
    color: #EEEEEE;
}

#menu li.nodropdown :hover a {
    color:#161616;
}
```

And I want to be able to call nodropdown class and override Button 2 like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Button 1</a></li>
    <li class="nodropdown"><a href="#">Button 2</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Button 2</a></li>
```

But I don't think the way I formatted the class for nodropdown is correct right above is correct? Could you help me corrected please?

Comment: nothing wrong with your example. Maybe if needed you could have added and 'a' style first above with base styles then a.nodropdown would only have any overrides or things unique to dropdown 'a' class

Comment: Please re-review above I changed the post to be more clear as to what I am trying to do! Thanks!!

Comment: would it not be much better to do it the otherway around. create a call called dropdown and only apply that to li that needs to be a dropdown then no overriding is needed.

Comment: you would then have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/G3XDb/

Comment: Well lets take your example you created. Let's say I wanted to change the Color, hover, and say font size of "Services" but I wanted to leave everything else purple and the same font. Without doing something like this <li style="font bla color bla etc...> Instead I want to do something like <li class="DifferentButtonStyleHere" and have a class for it in the css. How do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of grouping is to group CSS classes/IDs together and then only list out common attributes once for example.

```
/* Attributes for all boxes */
td.Box1, td.Box2, td.Box3 {padding: 3px 6px; font-weight: bold}

/* Unique box attributes */
td.Box1 {background: #fff}
td.Box2 {background: #000}
td.Box3 {background: #ccc}
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I re-updated my post at the very top to explain in more detail as to what I am trying to do. Could you please take a look at it and let me know if you see something wrong how I am creating the nodropdown class? Thank you!!

Comment: better to have a dropdown class the other way around then no need to override. this is how you would normally do it. for example: http://jsfiddle.net/G3XDb/1/

Comment: above just looks for the <ul> inside another <ul> much better

Comment: Well lets take your example you created. Let's say I wanted to change the Color, hover, and say font size of "Services" but I wanted to leave everything else purple and the same font. Without doing something like this `<li style="font bla color bla etc...>` Instead I want to do something like `<li class="DifferentButtonStyleHere"` and have a class for it in the css. How do you do that?